# CSS top not working for image and its container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a website in which student profiles are required. The top property is not working for the image container. I've tried changing the value multiple times but it doesn't work. Even applying it on the image itself is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

```css
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    background-color: white;
}

.card .img-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    left: 5%;
    height: 45%;
    top: 10%;
}

.card .img-container img {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
  
.card p {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.card .name {
      font-weight: 700;
}

.card table {
    width: 90%;
    left: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img-container"><img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/circle-270-1156833.png"></div>
            <p class="name">Name</p>
            <p>Total Bands</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Reading: </td><td>Speaking: </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Listening: </td><td>Writing: </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your problem with the image?

Comment: It's unclear what you asking for, *The top property is not working for the image container* What do you mean by that ?

Comment: I want it 5% from the top of the card but the top property doesn't seem to work. When I use JS in browser console, it works fine but css doesn't show the desired result. I've used a local image but to load it here, I've used an online image with same size

Comment: Please check my answer, I updated it!

Comment: a percentage value for the top property is based on the containing block's height one of which don't have an explicit height on, use `margin` or `transform:translateY(5%)` [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need `padding-top`:

```css
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    background-color: white;
}

.card .img-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    left: 5%;
    height: 45%;
    top: 10%;
    padding-top: 5%;
}

.card .img-container img {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
  
.card p {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.card .name {
      font-weight: 700;
}

.card table {
    width: 90%;
    left: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img-container"><img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/circle-270-1156833.png"></div>
            <p class="name">Name</p>
            <p>Total Bands</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Reading: </td><td>Speaking: </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Listening: </td><td>Writing: </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. It helps. By the way can you explain why this had to be used instead of top?

Comment: Check the comment by  Zohir Salak. Also, if the answer solved the question please mark it as accepted.

Comment: side note, I would much rather use `transform` on the actual image instead of messing with the whole box in case there might be a change in the future.